In beamer, what is a proper way of switching environments based on mode?
I'm using beamer (in presentation mode) with tuft-handout class (in article mode) to write class notes. I want to be able to use certain environments based on the mode.
For example, in the handout mode, I would like to use tuft-handout figure environments (figure* and marginfigure), while in the presentation mode, I want to use the figure environment.
Currently, I'm doing something like this (which doesn't work for all environments). Is there a better way to achieve this?
\documentclass{beamer}

% \documentclass[12pt, a4paper, fleqn]{tufte-handout}
% \usepackage{beamerarticle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \only<presentation>{ \begin{figure} }
    \only<article>{ \begin{figure*} }
      \includegraphics{image.jpg}
      \caption{Image 1}
    \only<presentation>{ \end{figure} }
  \only<article>{ \end{figure*} }
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You could define the "tuft-handout" environments to behave like figure in presentation mode:
\documentclass{beamer}

%\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn]{tufte-handout}
%\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\mode<presentation>{
  \newenvironment<>{figure*}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure*}
      \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
      \caption{Image 1}
  \end{figure*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Very useful! Thanks. Will this ignore arguments given to the environment if any (e.g. \begin{marginfigure}[3cm])?

@jak123 You could just try it

I did, and it worked fine. But I was wondering if this is always the case.
